# Error to import project STM32CubeMX to Eclipse (macOS) STM32F4 DISCOVERY

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, stm32, stm32f4discovery

When I set project in the STM32CubeMX and click in "Open Project" the follow error occurs:

[image]

I was reinstalled the JDK and JRE, I no have idea to solves this

Comment: remove everything and install again

Comment: Everything = CubeMX, SystemWorkbench, JRE and JDK?

Comment: Anyway import  project not open